# Ajax to convert string to object and return object in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

Currently the JSON string data is being displayed on the web page, but I would prefer it to be displayed in an object. The code below converts it to a string, but how do I convert it back to an object and display it.

```
function post(path, data, disp_id) {

    // convert the parameters to a JSON data string
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: "POST",
        data: json,
        success: function(rt) {
           console.log(rt);
            var json = JSON.parse(rt);

            $('#'+disp_id).empty();
            $.each(json, function(i,val) {
                console.log(val);

            $('#'+disp_id).append(JSON.stringify(val) + "<br/>");
            })
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by displaying an object?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP :

```
json_decode(String)
```

In JS :

```
JSON.parse(String)
```

Sources :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: `json_encode()` maybe? and besides the question doesn't have a PHP tag.

Comment: He is sending a Stringified JSON Object and wants to parse it, json_decode does that in PHP.

Comment: But the problem is in the front end not back end

Comment: Then I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i forgot to mention "promise" here

```
function post(path, data, disp_id) {

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

     $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(rt) {
           console.log(rt);
            var json = JSON.parse(rt);

            $('#'+disp_id).empty();
            $.each(json, function(i,val) {
                console.log(val);

            $('#'+disp_id).append(JSON.stringify(val) + "<br/>");
            })
              dfd.resolve(data);

        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });

   return dfd.promise();
};


$.when(post(path, data, disp_id)).done(function(data){
     console.log(data)
})
```

Advantages of this approach:-

1. you can have common method for multiple ajax() request
2. you can return success or failure message for caller